# Displaying rows with same Phone Number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following columns.

```
Userid, email, creationdate, pstn.
```

The table has multiple PSTN values. I want to display Userid, email, creationdate, pstn on the basisi of PSTN number.

For Example:

```
1 abc@mail 11-01-2012 123455
2 rrr@mail 12-01-2012 123455
3 eee@mail 13-01-2012 155455
4 www@mail 14-01-2012 155455
5 qqq@mail 15-01-2012 123455
```

Comment: where are you having trouble?

Comment: I wrote multiple queries using count, groupby, having but i want list them on the basis of pstn number. Like i mentioned above

Comment: so where PTSN = '155455'?

Comment: I posted an answer below, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: where is the query you have tried

Comment: select [UserID], [PSTN] 
  from [SmartCall].[dbo].[SIP Details]
  group by [PSTN],[UserID]

Comment: Use this: Select * from table_name
    ORDER BY PSTN;

Comment: what does this order by will do?

Comment: it sorts the results.

Comment: You need to be more specific on what you are trying to achieve here. Give us more details so we can understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
Select * from table_name
    ORDER BY PSTN;
```

Answer (score 0):

(1)Do you want to display all the details (Userid, email, creationdate, pstn) for PSTN number given by user?

OR

(2)you want to just sort result by PSTN number

OR

(3)you want details for some specific PSTN number

Ans.1) if you want to display all the details (Userid, email, creationdate, pstn) for PSTN number given by user

```
   DECLARE 
       PSTNum  number; 
    BEGIN 
       PSTNum :=&PSTNum; 
    Select * from Table_Name where pstn=PSTNum;
END; 
/
```

2) if you want to just sort result by PSTN number

```
Select * from table_name
    ORDER BY pstn;
```

3)you want details for some specific PSTN number

```
Select * from Table_Name where pstn=155455; (if you want details for pstn number 155455)
```

Next time please provide more details and clarity in your question.

Comment: I want to display all the information order by PSTN number

Comment: then check my ans.2

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for the following?

```
declare @tab table (userid int, email varchar(100), creationdate varchar(10), pstn int)

insert into @tab
select 1, 'abc@mail', '11-01-2012', 123455
union           
select 2, 'rrr@mail', '12-01-2012', 123455
union           
select 3, 'eee@mail', '13-01-2012', 155455
union           
select 4, 'www@mail', '14-01-2012', 155455
union           
select 5, 'qqq@mail', '15-01-2012', 123455

select * from @tab

select pstn, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(userid AS VARCHAR(100)) [text()]
         FROM @tab 
         WHERE pstn = t.pstn
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') userids,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(email AS VARCHAR(100)) [text()]
         FROM @tab 
         WHERE pstn = t.pstn
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') emails,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(creationdate AS VARCHAR(100)) [text()]
         FROM @tab 
         WHERE pstn = t.pstn
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') creationdates         
from @tab t
group by pstn
```

HTH!

Thanks.